# display specific category in prestashop tab homepage

Tags: prestashop, smarty, categories, product

I'd like to display in the new products tab in prestashop 1.6 homepage only products from a specific category

I use blocknewproducts_home.tpl

I tried this code below but nothing display from the category 114 (with get products attached)

```
{if $id_category == 114}
    {include file="$tpl_dir./product-list.tpl" products=$new_products class='blocknewproducts tab-pane' id='blocknewproducts'}
{/if}
{if isset($new_products) && $new_products}
    {include file="$tpl_dir./product-list.tpl" products=$new_products class='blocknewproducts tab-pane' id='blocknewproducts'}
{else}
    <ul id="blocknewproducts" class="blocknewproducts tab-pane">
        <li class="alert alert-info">{l s='No new products at this time.' mod='blocknewproducts'}</li>
    </ul>
{/if}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you sure `$id_category` is passed to view? Try to echo it.

Comment: Thanks four answer @r_a_f
I dont know how to check this inside the tpl

Comment: just add `{$id_category}` under `{if $id_category == 114}` I'm sure you don't pass it so you need check your controller to assign variable (id_category) (https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.assign.tpl)

Comment: And are you setting `$new_products` with products from category 114?

Answer (score 0):

try width : `{if $smarty.get.id_category == 114}`

Regards